# How do I root my Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900V)

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Guess I might as well grab this one since it doesn't exist. I listed my specific carrier's model in the question because that's *important*, however the CW post for rooting states there should only be one question per model, so answers for other versions of the GS5 are appropriate answers for this question, they just won't be marked as answer from me.

I haven't been able to find solid information for rooting the Samsung Galaxy S5, has anyone had experience with rooting this model?

Answer (score 2):

The Verizon and AT&T versions have locked bootloaders and are not able to be rooted at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Verizon and AT&T phone can now be rooted using towel root. Get it here http://towelroot.com

This exploit takes advantage of a vulnerability in the Linux kernel. I have tested this and it is working on my sm-g900v

Just download the apk and run it. Press the button once the so loads and you will be rooted in less than a second. Give props to geoshot who developed the exploit so that he will be inclind to do more work like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

CF autoroot
But it will trip knox

http://autoroot.chainfire.eu/

Comment: Not seeing the 900V listed at that link you provided.

Comment: Galaxy s4 had the same hardware on all carriers.
S5 should be the same way.
It will work. worst case scenario just means a trip to odin.